# Need to remove comma after last author (only)

Tags: punctuation, custom-bib

I'm trying to submit to a journal that has a non-standard bibliography format: citations look like this:

> **Gordon, R. H., C.-E. Bai, and D. D. Li**. 1999. "Efficiency Losses from Tax Distortions vs. Government Control," *European Economic Review*, 43, 1095-1103.

Anyhow, using custom-bib I've almost got a `bst` file that works.  I have two problems:

1) I have a trailing comma on the authors: e.g.

> **Gordon, R. H., C.-E. Bai, and D. D. Li**., 1999. ...

2) I'm missing the comma between volume and page .e.g:

> *European Economic Review*, 43 1095-1103.

I followed the instructions here to remove the comma after the last author here:

[remove comma after the last author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/remove-comma-after-the-last-author)

But that resulted in removing all of the commas.

Any suggestion on what to look for in the `bst` file would be helpful.  I really don't understand `bst` files.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing us how you call your bibliography (with or without `biblatex`) and include with package `filecontents` (`texdoc filecontents`) a short `bib` file. Also it would be helpful to see your `bst` file ...

Comment: If you created the `bst` using `makebst`, it would be helpful if you provided a link to the `bst` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've got it fixed.  The core of my problem was that when custom-bib asks how the blocks should be separated I shouldn't have selected the default: instead have it insert commas or periods explicitly instead of using newblocks.  At that point you can just find the format sections and just change the character to what you want.

Comment: can you show how we can do that?