# biblatex: remove comma after last author only in book

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, punctuation

I am using biblatex with the biber backend and the chem-acs style. 
For journals and inproceedings, the author list is printed followed by the title; however, for books and book chapters, there is a comma after the last author. I'd like to get rid of that extra comma.

For an MWE, please see below.

So far, I read some solutions to similar questions.
Both [remove comma after the last author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1783/remove-comma-after-the-last-author) and [Need to remove comma after last author (only)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85967/need-to-remove-comma-after-last-author-only) seem to work on manually created .bst files, and I would like to use the chem-acs style.

In the question [Colon (:) instead of period (.) after author with biblatex, alphabetic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28892/colon-instead-of-period-after-author-with-biblatex-alphabetic), a quite nice solution is given by

```
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
```

However, it seems that this only applies to journals and not to my "problematic" book types.

One solution seems to be to complete redefine the bibliograpy driver for book, but I'd like to circumvent that, because I only want to remove a single comma.

I had a look into the `chem-acs.bbx` file, and found the following definition:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
(...)
}
```

I noticed that if I comment out the line `\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock`, the comma stays. So I think it is defined somewhere inside the bibmacro for `author/translator+others`. However, I have no clue how to redefine that macro in a reasonable fashion, and to my best knowledge it is also not possible to redefine it only for types other than journal.

Here the MWE:

.tex file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[style=chem-acs,articletitle,chaptertitle,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}

  Some journals: \cite{Agrafiotis2000,Agrafiotis2003}
  A book, chapter, and inproceeding: \cite{Ozgur2005,Alpaydin2010,Joachims1999}

  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

.bib file:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{Ozgur2005,
  author = {{\"O}zg{\"u}r, Arzucan and {\"O}zg{\"u}r, Levent and G{\"u}ng{\"o}r,
Tunga},
  title = {{Text Categorization with Class-Based and Corpus-Based Keyword Selection}},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 20th International Conference on Computer and
Information Sciences},
  year = {2005},
  pages = {606-615},
}

@ARTICLE{Agrafiotis2000,
  author = {Dimitris K. Agrafiotis and Victor S. Lobanov},
  title = {{Nonlinear Mapping Networks}},
  journal = {Journal of Chemical Information and Computer Sciences},
  year = {2000},
  volume = {40},
  number = {6},
  pages = {1356-1362},
}

@ARTICLE{Agrafiotis2003,
  author = {Dimitris K. Agrafiotis and Huafeng Xu},
  title = {{A Geodesic Framework for Analyzing Molecular Similarities}},
  journal = {Journal of Chemical Information and Computer Sciences},
  year = {2003},
  volume = {43},
  number = {2},
  pages = {475-484},
}

@BOOK{Alpaydin2010,
  title = {{Introduction to Machine Learning}},
  publisher = {MIT Press},
  year = {2010},
  author = {Ethem Alpaydin},
  edition = {2nd},
}

@INBOOK{Joachims1999,
  chapter = {{Making Large-Scale Support Vector Machine Learning Practical}},
  pages = {169-184},
  title = {{Advances in Kernel Methods}},
  publisher = {MIT Press},
  year = {1999},
  editor = {Sch{\"o}lkopf, Bernhard and Burges, Christopher J. C. and Smola,
Alexander J.},
  author = {Joachims, Thorsten},
}
```

[image: Output: refs (4) and (5) contain commas after the authors]

Comment: Well, technically `Joachims1999` is not really right, `title = {{Advances in Kernel Methods}}` should be `booktitle = {{Advances in Kernel Methods}}` and `chapter = {{Making Large-Scale Support Vector Machine Learning Practical}},` should be `title = {{Making Large-Scale Support Vector Machine Learning Practical}},`

Comment: this is a valuable suggestion - thanks, I will check how the bibliography behaves if I change this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `chem-acs` style the `\newunitpunct` macro is defined as `\addcomma\addspace` so whenever you start a new unit you are going to get a comma. For `book` entries the unit is being started by the `maintitle+title` bibmacro while for `inbook` entries it is being started by the driver itself. While you could globally set `\newunitpunct`, this will have effects all over the place. Instead, I would use the [`xpatch`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package to patch the bibmacro and driver more locally and use `\setunit` to locally control the punctuation.

```
\xpatchbibmacro{maintitle+title}{\newunit\newblock}{\newunit\setunit{\addspace}\newblock}{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}{\usebibmacro{byauthor}\newunit}{\usebibmacro{byauthor}\newunit\setunit{\addspace}}{}{}
```

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately I get errors using the `xpatch` package:

`! Undefined control sequence. &lt;argument&gt; \ExplFileName`

This prevents me from trying at the moment.

Comment: also works perfectly, but with much less code than the solution below. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try the following.

The `bibdriver` for `inbook`, `incollection` and `inproceedings` do not seem to be quite right for the task, as the `\labelnamepunct` are *not* inserted directly before the `title`, but before other fields.

```
\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit
  \iftoggle{bbx:chaptertitle}
    {\usebibmacro{title}}
    {}%
```

Add the following lines to your preamble.
First, we renew the `maintitle+title`

```
\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+title}{%
  \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}
    {\clearfield{maintitle}%
     \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
     \clearfield{maintitleaddon}}
    {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{maintitle}}%
      %\newunit\newblock%<-- we comment this
    }%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
}

\newcommand{\patchcomma}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{title}}
    {\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock\usebibmacro{title}}
    {\typeout{patched macro (#1)}}{\typeout{failed to patch macro (#1)}}
}
\patchcomma{inbook}\patchcomma{incollection}
```

So we patch the `driver`s to include the `\labelnamepunct` directly before the `title`.

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=chem-acs,articletitle,chaptertitle,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@INPROCEEDINGS{Ozgur2005,
  author = {{\"O}zg{\"u}r, Arzucan and {\"O}zg{\"u}r, Levent and G{\"u}ng{\"o}r,
Tunga},
  title = {{Text Categorization with Class-Based and Corpus-Based Keyword Selection}},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 20th International Conference on Computer and
Information Sciences},
  year = {2005},
  pages = {606-615},
}

@ARTICLE{Agrafiotis2000,
  author = {Dimitris K. Agrafiotis and Victor S. Lobanov},
  title = {{Nonlinear Mapping Networks}},
  journal = {Journal of Chemical Information and Computer Sciences},
  year = {2000},
  volume = {40},
  number = {6},
  pages = {1356-1362},
}

@ARTICLE{Agrafiotis2003,
  author = {Dimitris K. Agrafiotis and Huafeng Xu},
  title = {{A Geodesic Framework for Analyzing Molecular Similarities}},
  journal = {Journal of Chemical Information and Computer Sciences},
  year = {2003},
  volume = {43},
  number = {2},
  pages = {475-484},
}

@BOOK{Alpaydin2010,
  title = {Introduction to Machine Learning},
  publisher = {MIT Press},
  year = {2010},
  author = {Ethem Alpaydin},
  edition = {2nd},
}

@INBOOK{Joachims1999,
  title = {{Making Large-Scale Support Vector Machine Learning Practical}},
  pages = {169-184},
  booktitle = {{Advances in Kernel Methods}},
  booksubtitle = {Support Vector Learning},
  publisher = {MIT Press},
  year = {1999},
  editor = {Sch{\"o}lkopf, Bernhard and Burges, Christopher J. C. and Smola,
Alexander J.},
  author = {Joachims, Thorsten},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+title}{%
  \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}
    {\clearfield{maintitle}%
     \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
     \clearfield{maintitleaddon}}
    {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{maintitle}}%
      %\newunit\newblock
    }%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
}

\newcommand{\patchcomma}[1]{%
  \xpatchbibdriver{#1}
    {\usebibmacro{title}}
    {\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock\usebibmacro{title}}
    {\typeout{patched macro (#1)}}{\typeout{failed to patch macro (#1)}}
}
\patchcomma{inbook}\patchcomma{incollection}
\begin{document}

  Some journals: \cite{Agrafiotis2000,Agrafiotis2003}
  A book, chapter, and inproceeding: \cite{Ozgur2005,Alpaydin2010,Joachims1999}

  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Are you allowed to have more than one `\labelnamepunct`? The documentation makes it sound like it controls sorting so won't this potentially cause problems?.

Comment: Thank you! I will also have a look tomorrow, today time's running out here.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub It might not be overly semantically sound, and I should probably have removed the first occurrence (but I could not be bothered and was not to sure about `language` before `title` anyway), but should have no adverse effect on anything else. (According to §4.10.1 *User-definable Commands and Hooks*, p. 211, of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf): "The default is `\newunitpunct`, i.e., it is not handled differently from regular unit punctuation but permits convenient reconfiguration.")

Comment: The renewing of `maintitle+title` worked for my `book` entry, thanks a lot! Unfortunately, I did not get the `xpatch` package to work (probably to my old tex installation).

Comment: perfectly working on another installation! thank you!