# Using colon ":" after author only for book and thesis, biblatex

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

I am using `biblatex` with `numeric` style. I would like to set it so I can have colon ":" after authors only for book and thesis. For all the rest I need a coma.

I was trying to use

```
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon \space}
```

which I found at [Colon (:) instead of period (.) after author with biblatex, alphabetic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28892/colon-instead-of-period-after-author-with-biblatex-alphabetic), but it sets colon for all types of documents.

Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you use

```
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifentrytype{book}} or test {\ifentrytype{thesis}}}
    {\addcolon\space}
    {\addcomma\space}}
```

Then you can get away without patching the drivers and it is slightly more obvious what it is you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I've come up with an answer based on:
[biblatex: remove comma after last author only in book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145012/biblatex-remove-comma-after-last-author-only-in-book)

In numeric thesis and book driver it is enough to change `nametitledelim` so I added:

```
\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}{\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}{\setunit{\addcolon \addspace} }{}{}
\xpatchbibdriver{book}{\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}{\setunit{\addcolon \addspace} }{}{}
```

To have coma for all the rest I used:

```
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\space}
```

Now it works as it is supposed to :)

Comment: You should use `{\addcomma\space}` instead of `{,\space}`.